# Liferay mobile responsive theme?

Tags: mobile, liferay, liferay-theme

Good morning everyone,

I have few questions about Liferay mobile and I would be glad if you could help me.

I am with Liferay 6.1, and I'm working to make an already existing portal more mobile and responsive.

- By following this link http://www.liferay.com/fr/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/liferay-com-mobile-sites-and-responsive-layouts
  For now, I just add a AUI.view in my main.js and it seems to work, even though I did not implement theses classes about differents width. Is it enough, or should I really implement these? What should I put in it, then?
- Also, I really would like to reach a responsiveness like that : http://www.realstorygroup.com/images/up/LiferayMobile1%281%29.png
  Do you have some tutorial or way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use CSS media queries to get your stylesheets responsive, rather than AUI-viewport, as media queries are much faster (and have pretty decent support nowadays) and now most Liferay themes make use of [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), which adds support for legacy browsers (in addition to making life a whole lot easier). The aui-viewport ship has sailed -- it just takes a while to get the internet up to speed :)

Making a Liferay site mobile-friendly isn't really a tutorial-able process. It's more about thinking about what content would need to be different between a desktop, tablet, and phone, and designing your site content and styles accordingly. The site image you included is changing up how it styles the nav menu based on the size of the screen, which should be fairly straightforward to do (I'm sure there's a tutorial out there somewhere for that portion of your needs). But from there, it all depends on what you have and where you need to get to with it.

[This page has some good discussion and even some code examples that should help you get started.](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/28066070)